# print multi-line text with spaces aligned on the first line

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

**Issue**:

I write relatively complex functions where I have to make up the code with spaces.

It is expected that the **first line with the content** (non-space character) will be determined, N spaces will be cut from it UP to the first non-space character.

Then, in all subsequent lines, the previously determined N-th number of spaces will also be cut out.

**Expectation examples**:

Let's say there is a certain `print` function.

In all subsequent cases, my expectation is:

```
this is the first line,
    this is the second line
  this is the third line.
```

Example of the cases used:

```bash
print '
    this is line one
        this is line two
      this is line three
    '
```

```bash
print '
            this is line one
                this is line two
              this is line three
            '
```

```bash
tmp() {
    tmp2() {
        print '
            this is line one
                this is line two
              this is line three
            '
    }
    tmp2
}
tmp
```

**UPD**: based on the practice of analyzing the answers to the issue, I added another one test:

```bash
tmp() {
    tmp2() {
        print '
            this
                this is line two
              this is line three
            '
    }
    tmp2
}
tmp
```

**P.S.: My developments (works incorrectly)**

```bash
print() {
    INPUT_STRING=$1
    
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010371/bash-counting-letters-in-string-output-always-a-little-different
    COUNT_SPACES_BEFORE_TEXT=$(printf '%s' "${INPUT_STRING}" | grep -o '[^\n]*' | wc -l)
    
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash
    STRING_SPACES=$(printf "%${COUNT_SPACES_BEFORE_TEXT}s" |tr " " " ")
    
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929235/multi-line-string-with-extra-space-preserved-indentation
    EXPR_SED='1d;$d;'
    EXPR_SED+="s/^${STRING_SPACES}//g"
    printf '%s' "${INPUT_STRING}" | sed "${EXPR_SED}"
}
```

Please tell me how to do it?

P.S.S.: please note that the input and output are strictly showed in the question.

1. It is not necessary to offer "similar" solutions like:

   ```
   printf '%s\n' \
       "this is line one" \
       "this is line two" \
       "this is line three"
   ```
2. No need to offer an analysis of my programming style, etc.

The entrance and exit are clearly indicated. I am going to ignore the answers/comments not on the subject

Comment: In all these cases, you're removing spaces based on the second line while claiming to want to do so based on the first line.

Comment: @muru - you're right, I corrected the query: "first line with the content"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a fan of using a function's positional arguments to pass a multiline string ... But if you always quote that string, then you can achieve what you want in **pure**(*i.e. using only shell builtins and no external commands used*) `bash` with a function like this:

```bash
my_print () { 
count=1
# Loop over multiline positional argument/s "$*" one line at a time
while IFS= read -r l; do
# Find the number of leading space characters in the first ...
# none empty/blank(all spaces) line and store it in "$spnum"
  if [ "$count" -eq "1" ] && [ ! -z "${l// /}" ]; then
    l2="${l//[^ ]*/}"
    spnum="${#l2}"
    count=2
    fi
# Print each none empty/blank(all spaces) line ...
# after removing "$spnum" characters from its beginning
  [ "$count" -eq "2" ] && [ ! -z "${l// /}" ] &&  echo "${l:spnum}"             
  done <<<"$*"
}
```

Usage demonstration:

```bash
$ my_print '
    this is line one
        this is line two
      this is line three
    '
this is line one
    this is line two
  this is line three
$
$ my_print '
            this is line one
                this is line two
              this is line three
            '
this is line one
    this is line two
  this is line three
$
$ tmp() {
    tmp2() {
        my_print '
            this is line one
                this is line two
              this is line three
            '
    }
    tmp2
}
tmp
this is line one
    this is line two
  this is line three
$
$ tmp() {
    tmp2() {
        my_print '
            this
                this is line two
              this is line three
            '
    }
    tmp2
}
tmp
this
    this is line two
  this is line three
```

Comment: Wow! Looks like what I need, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation with awk, assuming tabs are not whitespace.

```bash
print(){
  printf "%s" "$@" |
  awk 'BEGIN{ len = -1 }
  NF>0 { if(len==-1){
              len = index($0,$1)-1; 
              prefix = substr($0,1,len) 
         }
       }
  /./ { start = substr($0,1,len)
        if(start==prefix){
           if(length($0)>len)print substr($0,len+1)
        } else print
  }'
}
```

The string is piped into awk and each line tested. `len` is set to
-1.`NF>0` is true if the line is not all spaces. `$1` holds the first word.
The index of that word in the line `$0`, minus 1, is the length of the
prefix string of whitespace.

`/./` matches non-empty lines. The first `len` characters are put in
`start`. If this is the same as the prefix, the line is printed, starting
from position `len+1`, unless the line is exactly just the whitespace
prefix (such as at the end of the input; it is your choice). Else the
line, which doesn't have the right whitespace is printed, (your choice).

Comment: The proposed option looks interesting, thank you!
But I found a bug... (unfortunately, I can't pass the image/code in the comments). To reproduce it, it is enough to simply delete all other words from the first line, leaving only "this" - then the space-layout will float.

Comment: added the fourth test to the issue, marked as UPD

Comment: Oops, should be `NF>0` not `NF>1`. Sorry.